# How to show multiple options selected in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    belongs_to :editor
    belongs_to :catalog
    has_many :catalogs
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :catalog_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:catalog_id, @catalogs, :id, :ano, {:prompt => "Segure CTRL para seleção múltipla"}, {:multiple => true}) %>
</div>
```

controller:

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :format, :npag, :isbn, :sinopse, :image, :catalog_ids => [])
```

I can create new books but in the show.html.erb doesn't appear the selected itens, what is wrong?

I didn't change the show:

```
<%= @book.catalog %>
```

Comment: Please add the show.erb

Comment: Did you check if 'catalogs' has valid content at create? Put a raise @catalogs.inspect and check if there is anything there.

Comment: Yes, it has valid content (#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Catalog id: 1, year: "2014", created_at: "2014-10-03 18:51:03", updated_at: "2014-10-03 18:51:03">, #<Catalog id: 2, year: "2013", created_at: "2014-10-06 16:40:41", updated_at: "2014-10-06 16:40:41">]>)

Comment: @user3280355 It should be <%= @book.catalogs %> and remove `belongs_to :catalog` line in your model

Comment: Here is what is happening: #<Catalog::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x5439648> I'm researching a solution using map, is that right? I want that appears the catalog year

Comment: when you say: `belongs_to :catalog` in `Book` model then your `books` table is expected to have `catalog_id`. In case of `has_many :catalogs` catalogs` table will have `book_id`. So, in order to your show code: `<%= @book.catalog %>` you must have a valid value of `catalog_id`. For example: `@book.catalog = @book.catalogs.first` will set the first catalog as the book's catalog. But, it won't make any sense. It's better you remove `belongs_to :catalog` as anusha suggested.

Comment: I found some explanation about relationships here that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394803/rails-model-belongs-to-many. thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You should access each object to print its content:

```
<% @book.catalogs.each do |c| %>
<%= c.year %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hm, i got this: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: catalogs.book_id: SELECT "catalogs".* FROM "catalogs"  WHERE "catalogs"."book_id" = ?

Comment: Which kind of relation are you trying to do? Book 1 - N Catalogs, Books N - 1 Catalog, or Books N - N Catalogs?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:catalog_id, @catalogs, :id, :ano, {:prompt => "Segure CTRL para seleção múltipla", :selected => @catalogs.pluck(:id)}, {:multiple => true}) %>
```

You have to pass the selected option... `.pluck` will return an array of just ids of the catalogs... this relies on your show (and edit for that matter) method having `@catalogs = @book.catalogs`.