# Check if value already exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have 2 tables, one called movies and one called users. User can add a movie to their watchlist. When a user does so the app creates a new record in my movies table with the movie name, id, release date etc. So it's possible to have 3 records of the same movie. But all with different user id's. This is not preferable.

So I'm trying to figure out how to check if a record (movie with a `movie_id` value) already exists. If the movie already exists, to add the current users id to the `user id` colum so that multiple users can share the same movie record. If it does not exist yet, create a new record.

This is my current create function in my movies.rb controller,

```
def create
  respond_with Movie.create(movie_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
end
```

And in my movies model I have,

```
belongs_to :user
```

And I'm using Angular as my front-end framework, so this is my angular addMovie function,

```
  movieAdd.add()
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.movieListID = response;
      console.log ('Not empty' + $scope.movieListID)

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
        var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
        if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
            releaseNL = release;
        }
      }

      if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
        // With release date

        Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

        createMovie.create({
          title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
          release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
          image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
          movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
        }).then(init);

      } else {
        Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

        createMovie.create({
          title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
          release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
          image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
          movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
        }).then(init);
      };

    })
```

Comment: Your schema seems wrong.  What are you trying to model?  A user watching a movie or something?  If so you will need more models eg MovieUser which allows a "habtm" relationship between movies and users.

Comment: I was thinking I could insert the current users id into the movie user id collum. That collum could have multiple user ids.

Comment: This sounds ugly as hell, use a different table to model the relationship.  That's how rails works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find info about has-and-belongs-to-many and has-many through relationships [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394803/rails-model-belongs-to-many). I would use one of those two methods to setup the relationship between users and movies. Then, I think, in the movie function you would:

1. Check if the movie already exists in the database
2. Build the relation and respond with the existing movie if it does exist.
3. Create and respond with a new movie if it does not.

Comment: I'm trying to use the habtm method, but I'm having trouble setting up my controllers. How would you do this?